# numpy randomly sample boolean array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows.

```
data = np.array([True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False])
```

From the locations of 'True', I have to randomly sample 3 locations and keep them as True, besides them, convert as False.

I tried as:

```
indx = np.random.choice(len(data),3,replace=False)        
data[~indx] = False
```

How to do it in a better (1. easy, 2. performance, 3. elegance)?

```
print (data)
```

Also, how to sample only from 'True` locations?
My code is doing from all locations and incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For elegance, here's one -

```
n = 3
idx = np.flatnonzero(data)
r = np.random.choice(idx, n, replace=False)
data[idx[~np.isin(idx,r)]] = False
```

For performance -

```
s = data.sum()
t_mask = np.zeros(s, dtype=bool)
t_mask[np.random.choice(s, n, replace=False)] = True
data[data] = t_mask
```

Comment: @mk1 What do you mean difficult?

Comment: is not there more simple approach?

Comment: any alternative approach without using `np.setdiff1d`?

Comment: @mk1 Added in the post.

Comment: okay, though it is not part of the question, i'm interested to know if there is way to use random seed and stratification?

Comment: @mk1 What kind of stratification?

Comment: like in the code, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e5698bde9/sklearn/utils/__init__.py#L478

Comment: @mk1 Sounds too broad. Sorry, can't help on that.